# TypeError: models[model].defineConstraints is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I`m trying to undestand whats going on and why defineConstraints is not a function. can someone help me ?

Heres examples of my code.

index.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
  config = require('config');

const dbConf = config.get('database');
console.log(dbConf);


const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConf.database, dbConf.user, dbConf.password,{
  dialect: 'postgres',
  host: dbConf.host,
  port: dbConf.port,
  logging: console.log
});

sequelize.Model = Sequelize.Model;

const models = {
  User: sequelize.import(__dirname + '/models/user.js'),
  Service: sequelize.import (__dirname + '/models/service.js'),
  Subscriber: sequelize.import (__dirname + '/models/subscriber.js'),  
};

for(const model in models) {
  models[model].defineConstraints(models);
}

models.Op = Sequelize.Op;
models.sequelize = sequelize;

module.exports = models;
```

Comment: What version are you using? I don't see any indication that the `Sequelize` object supports a method called `import` (I was trying to see what its return value is; I'm guessing it's a promise). Sadly, the v7 docs seem to be missing the `Sequelize` class (the [v6 docs don't show any `import` method](https://sequelize.org/v6/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html)).

Comment: thanks a lot, the version...